# (Beginner SQL) Select rows based on the sum of other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Really weird Title to begin with. But you will totally understand the explanation.

Straight to the point, I have a table keeping track of the sales of different items.

```
+ -----+-------------+-------+----------+
| Name | Sell_Date   | Price | Quantity |
+ -----+-------------+-------+----------+
| Doll | 14-JAN-2005 | 12    | 2        |
| Bike | 07-FEB-2013 | 450   | 1        |
| Doll | 15-SEP-2016 | 12    | 5        |
+ -----+-------------+-------+----------+
```

Don't need more for the example.

So, with this table, I want to SELECT the Name of the items and sort them by the Sold Quantity (Ascending). With this in mind, the result should be Bike and then Doll. My problem is that some items may appear multiple times, thus needing their Quantity values added.

For I am a beginner, I am confused where I should do the SUM function, if I need to use the WITH method or not, and especially how I will do it for every specific item

Comment: You'd want to sum the quantity column and group by the Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a SUM and a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(QUANTITY)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  GROUP BY NAME
  ORDER BY SUM(QUANTITY) ASC
```

Comment: "and sort them by the Sold Quantity (Ascending)": `ORDER BY SUM(quantity)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - ["This is why we test things, people!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeM3t8pX1yA) - software design maxim of Dr. Octavius Brine, "Penguins of Madagascar" :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to aggregate at a specific level- in this case sum at the level of name-, you need to use a group by clause. But you need to be clear at what level to group and input those in the select field list. 
For your eg:

```
SELECT
name,
sum(Quantity) as tot_Quantity
FROM table
GROUP BY name -- this will give you per name the total quantity
ORDER BY 2 desc -- outputs with all the rows ordered descending by the second field in the select list
```

Aggregate at a much granular level :

```
SELECT 
name,
sell_date,
sum(Quantity) as tot_Quantity
FROM table
GROUP BY name,sell_date -- this will give you per name and date, total quantity
ORDER BY 3 desc -- outputs with all the rows ordered descending by the third field
```

Comment: That was a good idea to explain what GROUP BY does. (You don't *always* need a `GROUP BY` clause when aggregating though, for sometimes you just want a sum or count for the whole and not per xyz. Positional `ORDER BY` as shown has the disadvantage that you must be careful with adding columns. For this reason it is better to order by the expression (`order by sum(Quantity)`) or alias name (`order by tot_Quantity`).

Comment: Thanks for you comments Thorsten. I made some edits :)